# \hypersetup options 'pdftoolbar' and 'pdfmenubar' have no effect

Tags: packages, viewers, hyperlink

I tried to use in my latex document some `\hypersetup` options, but they don't work.

The options are:

> - pdftoolbar=true
> - pdfmenubar=true

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}                   
\hypersetup{
% pdfKeywords={},
pdftoolbar=true,
pdfmenubar=true,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=green,
filecolor=magenta,
urlcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{prova}
testo di prova

\section{prova sezione}
testo di sezione

\chapter{prova2}
testo di prova 2


\end{document}
```

When I try to compile the editor TeXMaker is not able to finish to compile and I 
am forced to quit the application.

Notice: if i compile only this i have no problem, but no menu or toolbar.
If i compile with more packages i have problems ...

Comment: Don't show only some snippets but a complete example demonstrating the problem that we can test.

Comment: I have no problem in compiling this example. Adobe Acrobat Reader complies to the setting of `pdftoolbar`, but does nothing different when the setting to `pdfmenubar` is changed. Other PDF viewers may not be affected by those options.

Comment: maybe are not usefull... it's bettere to delete these lines